# Equation parser efficiency

Tags: c++, performance, parsing, equation

I sunk about a month of full time into a native C++ equation parser.  It works, except it is slow (between 30-100 times slower than a hard-coded equation).  What can I change to make it faster?

I read everything I could find on efficient code.  In broad strokes:

- The parser converts a string equation expression into a list of "operation" objects.
- An operation object has two function pointers: a "getSource" and a "evaluate".
- To evaluate an equation, all I do is a for loop on the operation list, calling each function in turn.

There isn't a single if / switch encountered when evaluating an equation - all conditionals are handled by the parser when it originally assigned the function pointers.

- I tried inlining all the functions to which the function pointers point - no improvement.
- Would switching from function pointers to functors help?
- How about removing the function pointer framework, and instead creating a full set of derived "operation" classes, each with its own virtual "getSource" and "evaluate" functions?  (But doesn't this just move the function pointers into the vtable?)

I have a lot of code.  Not sure what to distill / post.  Ask for some aspect of it, and ye shall receive.

Comment: As far as I know, inlining is just a *hint* for the compiler, not a command. Maybe try compiling with optimization (`-O3` or something)...

Comment: In fact you can't inline functions that you call dynamically through pointers since the compiler doesn't know what function (if any) you're actually calling.

Comment: Perhaps you should look into outputting bytecode at run time. On Windows, you can specify a memory location that is executable. You can output the series of assembly instructions corresponding to your equation. This usually gets you close to unoptimized, hard coded equations.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses, I am very impressed with stackoverflow and its community.  Just a few quick things to add: I'm not concerned about the parsing time.  It stores the operationList, so it only parses once for every (about) million evaluations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your description if the slowness includes parsing, or it is just the interpretation time.

The parser, if you write it as recursive-descent (LL1) should be I/O bound. In other words, the reading of characters by the parser, and construction of your parse tree, should take a lot less time than it takes to simply read the file into a buffer.

The interpretation is another matter.
The speed differential between interpreted and compiled code is usually 10-100 times slower, unless the basic operations themselves are lengthy.
That said, you can still optimize it.

You could profile, but in such a simple case, you could also just single-step the program, in the debugger, at the level of individual instructions.
That way, you are "walking in the computer's shoes" and it will be obvious what can be improved.

Whenever I'm doing what you're doing, that is, providing a language to the user, but I want the language to have fast execution, what I do is this:
I translate the source language into a language I have a compiler for, and then compile it on-the-fly into a .dll (or .exe) and run that.
It's very quick, and I don't need to write an interpreter or worry about how fast it is.

Comment: In addition to profiling, I will try single-stepping as you suggest.  But I did design it with the strategy you mention - becoming one with the computer ;)

Comment: @Marupio: Also, sleep on it, and then try the compile-on-the-fly approach. You print out a program file, exec the compiler and linker to make a .dll file, and then load the .dll and locate the entry point you want to call. That all takes about a second. Then you can run the code at top speed. I've done this more times than I can count. It flies.

Comment: I like your suggestion, now that I've reread it and understood it. I can output the code to a source file, but not sure how to call a compiler on the fly.  I'll look into it. This will probably be for the next version. Thanks!

Comment: @Marupio: I just write out a batch file to a handy directory. Then there's some nonsense about creating a process and waiting for it to complete. Functions are called `CreateProcess` that gives you a handle and `WaitForSingleObject`. Then to load the dll it's `LoadLibrary`. To get the call points, it's `GetProcAddress`.

Answer (score 5):

In your post you don't mention that you have profiled the code. This is the first thing I would do if I were in your shoes. It'll give you a good idea of where the time is spent and where to focus your optimization efforts.

Comment: I haven't profiled the code yet.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I know the bottleneck is in evaluation, not parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing is: Profile what actually went wrong. Is the bottleneck in parsing or in evaluation? valgrind offers some tools that can help you here.

If it's in parsing, boost::spirit might help you. If in evaluation, remember that virtual functions can be pretty slow to evaluate. I've made pretty good experiences with recursive boost::variant's.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about the parsing time.  This happens up front.  I use the evaluation about a million times as often as parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You know, building an expression recursive descent parser is really easy, the LL(1) grammar for expressions is only a couple of rules. Parsing then becomes a linear affair and everything else can work on the expression tree (while parsing basically); you'd collect the data from the lower nodes and pass it up to the higher nodes for aggregation.

This would avoid altogether function/class pointers to determine the call path at runtime, relying instead of proven recursivity (or you can build an iterative LL parser if you wish).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using a quite complicated data structure (as I understand it, a syntax tree with pointers etc.). Thus, walking through pointer dereference is not very efficient memory-wise (lots of random accesses) and could slow you down significantly. As Mike Dunlavey proposed, you could compile the whole expression at runtime using another language or by embedding a compiler (such as LLVM). For what I know, Microsoft .Net provides this feature (dynamic compilation) with Reflection.Emit and Linq.Expression trees.

Comment: That's what I was concerned about.  In fact, to handle the function pointers, my equationReader calls a "callFunctionPointer" function in my operation object, which in turn calls the function in the equationReader.  I was about to address this silliness, but thought maybe the whole structure needs changing.  As for compile at runtime, this already exists in the project but, 1. I'm too far in - don't want to give up the parser, and 2. I want user to enter Excel-like equations, not source code.

Comment: @Marupio Well, I don't really know how your source code looks like, but porting from basic c++ (pointers, references and functions, no crazy template metaprogramming stuff) to c# is quite simple. And then, you could use your parser to generate an AST (abstract syntax tree) from whatever the user input looks like. Then, generate code from this AST and compile it on the fly with .Net JIT.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those rare times that I'd advise *against* profiling just yet. My immediate guess is that the basic structure you're using is the real source of the problem. Profiling the code is rarely worth much until you're reasonably certain the basic structure is reasonable, and it's mostly a matter of finding which parts of that basic structure can be improved. It's not so useful when what you really need to do is throw out most of what you have, and basically start over.

I'd advise converting the input to RPN. To execute this, the only data structure you need is a stack. Basically, when you get to an operand, you push it on the stack. When you encounter an operator, it operates on the items at the top of the stack. When you're done evaluating a well-formed expression, you should have exactly one item on the stack, which is the value of the expression.

Just about the only thing that will usually give better performance than this is to do like @Mike Dunlavey advised, and just generate source code and run it through a "real" compiler. That is, however, a fairly "heavy" solution. If you really need maximum speed, it's clearly the best solution -- but if you just want to improve what you're doing now, converting to RPN and interpreting that will usually give a pretty decent speed improvement for a small amount of code.

Comment: I should have thought of RPN.  Still, I think my efficiency loss comes from dynamically trying to find the correct operation to perform - this would also be a problem with RPN.  If RPN says "3 4 +", what is the most efficient way to get it to execute addition(), one among 60 possible functions / operators?  You mentioned @Mike Dunlavey's response, so I reread it, and realize I didn't quite understand what he was saying.  It sounds heavy, but I think I may try it.

Comment: @Marupio: Usually, you want to assign a range of consecutive values to the operators you use instead of using human-readable symbols. A switch statement is usually at least as fast as the alternatives. An array/vector of pointers to functions/functors *looks* like it would be faster, but in my testing usually ends up slower than a `switch`.

Comment: As far as @Mike's idea goes, it seems to be pretty simple: instead of interpreting the expression, just put it into a C (or whatever) skeleton, compile that to a DLL/SO, then dynamically load the result into your program.